# simple preg_match needed

Tags: php

The conditions of the preg_match are:

1. can only contain letters (upper or lower case) and numbers
2. must begin with a letter

Here is what I have at the moment:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/
```

This works for the first condition but not the second.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/^[A-Z][A-Z0-9]*$/i`

Comment: Thank you Sir, just what I was after.

Comment: It would also be worth adding the `D` modifier since a pesky trailing newline would break the conditions set out in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Put the more restrictive character class as the first character, i.e. `/^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-z0-9]*$/`

I changed the + to a * so that more than 1 character is not required (* will let the regex match "a", + would need to be a with something after it.